# locate.updatedb not indexing ~/Library

Tags: macos, locate

I know there's a file deep in ~/Library called index.js. I can find it with the find command `find ~/Library -name "index*"`(it actually finds a lot of similarly named files).

However when I do `locate index` there's nothing to be found in ~/Library.  It does find other files in ~/ but none in ~/Library

I've repeated this with several different files and it doesn't look like anything in ~/Library is being indexed.

So I run `sudo /usr/libexec/locate.updatedb` thinking the database just needed updating.  No dice.

So I look in /etc/locate.rc to see if I'm doing something stupid with PRUNEPATHS or SEARCHPATHS.  I'm not doing anything.  Everything is the default.  Just for kicks I set SEARCHPATHS="/Users/me/Library/" while locate.updatedb runs extremely quickly, `locate`  gives the same results as before.

I'm completely baffled at this point.  Can anyone help?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is just a guess, but recent versions of macOS restrict access to "private" files, including parts of ~/Library (see [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/332673/what-and-how-does-macos-mojave-implement-to-restrict-applications-access-to-pers)), and it may be that the process building the locate database doesn't have access to the file you're looking for.

Comment: I had that problem once before and made sure iTerm has Full Disk Access.

Comment: Is the indexing process run under iTerm?

Comment: When I do it manually, yes

Comment: In that case, it looks like my guess is wrong.